# having pairs of equal objects generate lists of equal objects

Tags: python

I have list of objects ids and a list of tuples representing all possible combinations of tests for equality between the objects:

```
objects_ids=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
tests = [
    (1, 2, 0),
    (1, 3, 0),
    (1, 4, 1),
    (1, 5, 1),
    (1, 6, 0),
    (2, 3, 1),
    (2, 4, 0),
    (2, 5, 0),
    (2, 6, 0),
    (3, 4, 0),
    (3, 5, 0),
    (3, 6, 0),
    (4, 5, 1),
    (4, 6, 0),
    (5, 6, 0),
]

(1, 4, 1) - means that object #1 is equal to object #4
(1, 2, 0) - means that #1 is NOT equal to object #2
```

I need to generate groups of equal objects so the result will look like:

```
[[1,4,5], [2,3], [6]]
```

Is there a more or less efficient way of doing it?

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to do. Can you explain more ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your resulting list. Can you give more explanation?

Comment: What is the output of `(4, 5, 1),`? You are ignoring it? And where did this `[6]` come from?

Comment: Could you please provide the solution you attempted? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called connected components. You have to add all nodes and then the edges:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,4)  
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(4,5)  

for i in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
{1, 4, 5}
{2, 3}
{6}
```

Comment: is there a way to include cliques of size one?

Comment: nx.nodes(G), which will give all the nodes. That is the true Clique of size 1 its not just [6]

Comment: can same id appear in multiple cliques? like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817086/object-appears-in-multiple-graph-cliques

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick

```
>>> t = [[i] + [t[1] for t in tests if t[0] == i and t[2]] + [t[0] for t in tests if t[1] == i and t[2]] for i in objects_ids]
>>> t = [list(set(k)) for k in t]
>>> t np.unique(t)
[list([1, 4, 5]) list([2, 3]) list([6])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try :

```
same_objects = [i[:2] for i in tests if i[2] == 1]
main = []
for i in same_objects:
    temp = []
    for j in same_objects:
        if set(i).intersection(set(j)):
            temp.append(j)
    main.append(temp)

unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in s)]
final_list = [list(set(sum(i, ()))) for i in unique_data]
final_list.append(list(set(objects_ids) - set(sum(final_list, []))))
print(final_list)
```

Output will be like :

```
[[1, 4, 5], [2, 3], [6]]
```