# object appears in multiple graph cliques

Tags: django, graph, artificial-intelligence, networkx, graph-theory

I have a piece of code that supposed to find cliques of nodes, while nodes are ids of django model objects:

```
    import networkx as nx
    final_groups = []
    graph = nx.Graph()
    for img_test in Same_Img_Test.objects.filter(id__in=test_ids, is_same=1):
        graph.add_edge(img_test.product_1.id, img_test.product_2.id)
    for x in nx.find_cliques(graph):
        final_groups.append(x)
        print x
```

I get this result:

```
[1293856L, 909760L]
[1293856L, 909730L]
[1293856L, 909797L]
[1293856L, 909767L]
[1293856L, 909741L]
```

my question id: **how same id (`1293856L`) can occur in multiple cliques?**
isn't the result supposed to be something like:

```
[1293856L, 909760L, 909730L, 909797L, 909767L, 909741L]
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
what I was looking for was `nx.connected_components(graph)` instead of `nx.find_cliques(graph)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, same ID can be present in multiple cliques (of same size or different size).

I think that you are showing just the cliques of size 2, may be your expected output would be there in down below.

`[1293856L, 909760L, 909730L, 909797L, 909767L, 909741L]` would come out as one of the clique only when each pair of these ID has an edge between them in the given graph.

Comment: so I guess what I was looking for was `nx.connected_components(graph)`